# How to split only one row value and insert into multiple columns using stored procedure, parameter value is from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcTeamInfoById]
   (@id INT, 
    @txtName VARCHAR(50), 
    @phone VARCHAR(100), 
    @contactname VARCHAR(100),                    
    @address VARCHAR(300), 
    @email VARCHAR(100),  
    @captain VARCHAR(100), 
    @requirements VARCHAR(50))
AS                    
BEGIN
    IF @id = -1                    
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @teamID VARCHAR(MAX);

        INSERT INTO TeamDetails(TeamName, Phone, ContactName, Address, Email, captain)               
        VALUES (@txtName, @phone, @contactname, @address, @email, @captain)    

        SET @teamID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();    

        // Here now I need to add to different table...

        // checkbox checked values 

        INSERT INTO teamrequirements (teamid, requirement, value) 
        VALUES (@teamID, @requirements, 1)

        // Here I am getting 1, bats, Gloves, 1
    END
    ELSE
       UPDATE TeamDetails 
       SET TeamName = @txtName, Phone = @phone, 
           ContactName = @contactname,                     
           Address = @address, Email = @email, 
       WHERE TeamId = @id  
    END
```

I need like this how to modify stored procedure

```
1, bats,gloves,1
```

I need to insert as

```
1 bats 1 
2 gloves1
```

If I need to update the above it should be like

```
1 bats  1
```

If I updating with no values it should be like

```
1  '' ''
```

My stored procedure inserts into two tables. While adding into `teamrequirements` table, I need to split one column value into multiple columns where I commented. I need to modify the stored procedure to insert into multiple columns and records 
in the `teamrequirements` table.

How to do it?

While adding a team is added into the `teamdetails` table, and I have checkbox like Requirements if I check that I can select another two checkboxes, when both checkboxes are checked, two records to be inserted in teamrequirements, example , i wil have teamid, requirement, value...example 1,bats,Gloves,1 this should insert as 2 records Like

```
12,1 bat , 1 // 12 is record id in teamrequirements
13,1,Gloves , 1 // 13 is record id in teamrequirements
```

Please help...

What if it is Update in the same procedure ..
 update teamrequirements set requirement= @reuirement , value = 1 where teamid = @id  in this case , if i add those two records bats gloves in database i am adding records , what if i need to clear those added records using update statement in the same procedure

Comment: The question is difficult to understand, but it sounds like you need to re-design how Requirements is constructed. It seems like @Requirements should be a Table Valued Parameter (google-able term) that has a row for each requirement.

Comment: While adding a team i team is added in teamdetails table , and i have checkbox like Requirements if i check that i can select another two checkboxes , when both checkboxes are checked , two records to be inserted in teamrequirements, example , i wil have teamid, requirement, value...example 1,bats,Gloves,1 this should insert as 2 records..

Comment: That doesn't exactly clear it up for me, but now maybe I think you just need to split `@Requirements` into separate nullable variables. Regardless, it seems clear `@Requirements` is not appropriate to communicate what you need in your procedure.

Comment: I need to split @requirements into multiple records ..using stored procedure ..

Comment: I am getting bats,Gloves and stroing in same column , there i need to split into multiple columns like , Teamid , bat , 1 and Teamid , Gloves ,1 Teamid i get from scope identity

Comment: I get that part, but one variable is not appropriate for communicating that information unless it is a table valued parameter.

Comment: Yes , i am trying to modify my stored procedure but i am not able to do it.. could you plz help me

Comment: I won't help you Google but I will help you when what you have tried based on your research doesn't work right (though I will be away from computer soon). If you will always have just one or two rows to insert then just create multiple nullable parameters and only insert if the id (or whatever) is not null. But I assume you will extend equipment to be more than just bats and gloves so I think the work to research and learn table valued parameters is worth it. If you come across advice regarding splitting strings on commas please resist doing it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of the [split function over the internet or create your own](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1665/sql-server-clr-and-sql-split-functions-to-parse-a-delimited-string/) and use it. Below code has been written according to split function in [FnSplitString](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/).

You created a split function in your database. This function will return 1 or more values from your string provided. This is your `@requirements` variable.

```
IF(LEN(@requirements) > 0)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO teamrequirements (teamid, requirement, value) 
    SELECT @teamID, splitdata, '1' FROM dbo.[fnSplitString](@requirements,',')
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO teamrequirements (teamid, requirement, value) 
   VALUES (@teamID, '', '') 
END
```

**SQL 2016**:

[JSON support](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/json-support-in-sql-server-2016/) is there now. So, you can pass string as json and take 2 values into key value table, and insert it directly. No need to split.

**FOR UPDATE:**
You can take this split string data in a table variable. Update data from table variable as source into main table, with a JOIN condition.

```
DECLARE @id INT = 40

DECLARE @data TABLE
(
Id INT,
Requirement VARCHAR(50),
Value INT
)

DECLARE @requirements VARCHAR(50) = 'bat,gloves,ball'
INSERT INTO @data
SELECT @id, splitdata, 1 FROM dbo.[fnSplitString](@requirements,',')

SELECT * FROM @data

-- SOMETHING LIKE THIS CAN BE YOUR UPDATE QUERY
UPDATE a SET 
value = b.Value
FROM teamrequirements a INNER JOIN @data b ON a.id = b.Id 
and a.requirement = b.Requirement
```

**MERGE SAMPLE:**

```
MERGE teamrequirements AS TARGET
USING @data AS SOURCE 
ON TARGET.id = SOURCE.Id AND TARGET.requirement = SOURCE.Requirement
--When records are matched, update 
--the records if there is any change
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET TARGET.value = SOURCE.Value
--When no records are matched, insert
--the incoming records from source
--table to target table
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
INSERT (teamid, requirement, value) 
VALUES (SOURCE.Id, SOURCE.Requirement, SOURCE.Value);
```

Comment: Ugh, can we please stop advising people to split strings when we have been able to do it right since SQL 2005?

Comment: @Crowcoder His use case is like this. Otherwise, he should not be bringing multiple data in one variable. Better use XML data type in that case, or create own table type. But currently, his question and use case is such.

Comment: Additionally, both "rows" are in the same string so it would require additional awkward T-SQL to break them out.

Comment: Good suggestion with XML, it's easier to setup but there is a trade off with the incomprehensible way to work xml in T-SQL.

Comment: no i am not able to get the output , i am getting a error

Comment: Have you created SplitString function from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/ in your database.

Comment: yes i have created , I am getting a slight problem when update the same records

Comment: [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: @Jones The string contains multiple rows worth of data, you have more work to do after splitting it. Splitting it is not appropriate here. If you must I would do it in C# then run multiple updates instead of doing it from the stored procedure.

Comment: @amit what if i want to update the records which are added  in the same procedure.its working fine for insert , how to do for update

Comment: @amit update is not working , insert is working fine

Comment: @Jones you need to treat `@data` as table, and join it with other table for the update query.

Comment: Something like this UPDATE a SET 
value = b.Value
FROM teamrequirements a INNER JOIN @data b ON a.id = b.Id 
and a.requirement = b.Requirement

Comment: DECLARE @requirements VARCHAR(50) = 'bat,gloves,ball' here i am getting error

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: @Amit suppose if i add only 1 record while inserting , while updating from front end, if i check 3 checkboxes  and click save , 2 more records need to be added

Comment: You need to use MERGE command then. Give teamRequirements table as Target, and @data as Source, USE WHEN MATCHED for UPDATE, and WHEN NOT MATCHED for INSERT. A good example is here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156267/discussion-between-jones-and-amit).

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be better to use table valued parameters for this.

Without that, you can split the string (this demo uses delimitedsplit8k by Jeff Moden) , and you could use `merge` to handle changes. It makes sense to move this into its own procedure and call that procedure from your current one.

*TL;DR:* rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PVX88970

The `TeamRequirements_Merge` procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.TeamRequirements_Merge (
    @TeamId int
  , @requirements varchar(8000)
) as
begin;
  set nocount, xact_abort on;
  /* it would be much better to use table valued parameters for this */
  ;with t as (
    select TeamId, Requirement, Value
    from TeamRequirements
    where TeamId = @TeamId
  )
  , s as (
    select
        TeamId = @TeamId
      , Requirement = coalesce(s.item,'') -- since you want blanks
      , Value = 1
    from dbo.[delimitedsplit8K](@requirements,',') s
  )
  merge into t with (holdlock)
  using s
    on t.TeamId = s.TeamId
   and t.Requirement = s.Requirement
  when matched and t.value <> s.value
    then update set t.value = s.value
  when not matched by target
    then insert (TeamId, Requirement, Value)
      values (s.TeamId, s.Requirement, s.Value)
  when not matched by source
    then delete
  --output $Action, inserted.*, deleted.* /* for testing */
  ;
end;
go
```

The revised `ProcTeamInfoById` procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[ProcTeamInfoById] (
    @id int
  , @txtName varchar(50)
  , @phone varchar(100)
  , @contactname varchar(100)
  , @address varchar(300)
  , @email varchar(100)
  , @captain varchar(100)
  , @requirements varchar(8000)
  ) as
begin;
  if @id = -1
    begin;
      insert into TeamDetails(TeamName, Phone, ContactName, Address, Email, captain)
      values (@txtName, @phone, @contactname, @address, @email, @captain);

      set @id = scope_identity();
    end;
  else
    begin;
       update TeamDetails
       set TeamName = @txtName, Phone = @phone,
           ContactName = @contactname,
           Address = @address, Email = @email
       where TeamId = @id;
    end;
  exec dbo.TeamRequirements_Merge @id, @requirements;
end;
go
```

---

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)
- [Ordinal workaround for **`string_split()**` - Solomon Rutzky](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2433171)

`merge` reference:

- [Use Caution with SQL Server''s `MERGE` Statement - Aaron Bertrand](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)
- [UPSERT Race Condition With `Merge` - Dan Guzman](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx)
- [An Interesting `MERGE` Bug - Paul White](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/03/another-interesting-merge-bug.aspx)
- [Can I optimize this `merge` statement - Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/can-i-optimize-this-merge-statement/44069#44069)
- [If you are using indexed views and `MERGE`, please read this! - Aaron Bertrand](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug)
- [The Case of the Blocking `Merge` Statement (LCK_M_RS_U locks) - Kendra Little](https://www.littlekendra.com/2016/05/24/the-case-of-the-blocking-merge-statement-lck_m_rs_u-locks/)
- [Writing t-sql `merge` statements the right way - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2013/05/writing-t-sql-merge-statements-the-right-way/)

---

Again, it would be better to use table valued parameters for this:

Table Valued Parameters reference:

- [Table-Valued Parameters - msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx)
- [User-Defined Table Types - msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 Table-Valued Parameters and C# Custom Iterators: A Match Made In Heaven! - Leonard Lobel](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/)
- [Table Value Parameter Use With C# - Jignesh Trivedi](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/table-value-parameter-use-with-C-Sharp/)
- [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)
- [Maximizing Performance with Table-Valued Parameters - Dan Guzman](http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/)
- [Maximizing throughput with tvp - sqlcat](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2013/09/23/maximizing-throughput-with-tvp/)
- [How to use TVPs with Entity Framework 4.1 and CodeFirst](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179481/Code-First-Stored-Procedures)

Comment: Thanks for the respponse..can i get the modifiction for inserting the records and updating the same records .

Comment: @jones this already does that, as shown in the demo. Am I misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: sorry i havent tested..example . while inserting 1, bats ,gloves, money, 1 should be saved as// 1 bats 1, 1,gloves,1 ,1 ,money, 1 ..1 is team id and 1 is bit true.. the same records if i want to update like 1,'',0 bases on recordid stored in db table teamrequirements

Comment: @Jones I have no idea what you are saying, but I included a link to the demo in my answer http://rextester.com/PVX88970